# Remove Content-Security-Policy from response header in local (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, http-headers, content-security-policy

I'm having issues only when running my application locally.

It looks like I have a `Content-Security-Policy` set to `'none'` by default.

I recently migrated from Angular 7 to Angular 8 in order to make lazy loading easier to implement, but I don't see why this would put a CSP header to `default-src 'none'` by default.

Besides, it worked just fine for a while.

However, when I start my application locally, in the response Header, I see this line :

`Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'`

I'm also pointing out that this line is not present in the response header on the Development and Tests Environments.

Response header in local :

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 139
Date: Mon, 28 Oct 2019 16:14:09 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

In the other environments, the response header doesn't include the `Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'` line.

Also, I've tried to add this line to my index.html file :

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'"/>`

But this didn't change a thing, it's probably overridden by the http server (Webpack ?).

I suppose that on my Development and Tests environments, My Apache is configured not to use CSP, so the header doesn't include a `Content-Security-Policy`.

How can I make it the same locally ? Since it's Angular 8, I don't have access to the Webpack configuration, I believe it's handled in `@angular-devkit/build-angular` instead. (Although, it can be acessed via a plugin such as `custom-webpack` I've read, But I'd rather avoid it)

I don't think Angular uses a default configuration where `Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'` is the default policy. (it should at least be `self`)

Finally, here is a part of the angular.json file, the local conf used to build :

```
  "configurations": {
    "local": {
      "optimization": true,
      "outputHashing": "none",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "extractCss": true,
      "namedChunks": true,
      "aot": false,
      "extractLicenses": true,
      "vendorChunk": false,
      "buildOptimizer": false
    },
```

Let me know if another configuration file (tsconfig, package...) can be useful in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like it's caused by the `--deployUrl` build option.

I removed it from my angular.json file, and the error went away after a rebuild.
So I'm guessing Angular adds a restrictive CSP header when the deploy url is present.